# How to dynamically add mat-icon to divs with angular renderer2?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a HTML with a lot of divs. I have already generated divs that look like this.

**static HTML (not dynamically generated) example of desired result using renderer2**

```html
    <div class="time-rowss clearfixx" #timerowss>
      <div><mat-icon>today</mat-icon> date </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-rows clearfix" #timerows>
      <div><mat-icon>brightness_3</mat-icon>00:00</div>
      <div><mat-icon>brightness_3</mat-icon>01:00</div>
      <div><mat-icon>brightness_3</mat-icon>02:00</div>
    </div>
```

I want to achieve the same but dynamically generating the divs.

What I have done so far is add dynamically times and dates.

Here is my code:

```
for (let j = this.requestVehicle.startDateTime.getDate(); j < this.requestVehicle.endDateTime.getDate(); j++) {
  const newTime = new Date(time.getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000);
  time = newTime;
  const date = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.appendChild(date, this.renderer.createText(newTime.getDate() + '/' + newTime.getMonth() + '/' + newTime.getFullYear()));
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.d7.nativeElement, date);
  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    const b = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const icon = this.renderer.createElement('mat-icon');
    if (i < 7 || i > 18) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(icon, 'svgIcon', '"brightness_3"');
    } else {
      this.renderer.setProperty(icon, 'svgIcon', '"wb_sunny"');
    }
    let text;
    if (i >= 10) {
      text = ' ' + i;
    } else {
      text = '0' + i;
    }
    this.renderer.appendChild(b, icon);
    this.renderer.appendChild(b, this.renderer.createText(text + ':00'));
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.d3.nativeElement, b);
  }
}
```

I have tried several options:

- this.renderer.setProperty(icon, 'svgIcon', '"wb_sunny"');
- this.renderer.setProperty(icon, 'svgIcon', 'wb_sunny');
- this.renderer.setAttribute(icon, 'svgIcon', '"brightness_3"');
- this.renderer.setAttribute(icon, 'svgIcon', 'brightness_3');
- this.renderer.appendChild(icon, this.renderer.createText('brightness'));
- this.renderer.appendChild(icon, 'brightness_3');

none of these options work. I also tried iconName instead of svgIcon.

how should I add iconName or svgIcon with renderer2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I what I was noticed when I tried to add mat-icon value with renderer createText. It was adding it correctly. The problem was that the IconName was appearing in html as name not as an icon. So I realized the css was missing. I looked into the dev tools and inspected the divs and mat-icons. I found out that they were missing classes.

So I added the classes manually.

**In short**

**you need to create mat-icon element**.

```
const dateIcon = this.renderer.createElement('mat-icon');
```

**add value using createText.**

```
this.renderer.appendChild(dateIcon, this.renderer.createText('today'));
```

**give classes for css styling.**

```
  this.renderer.addClass(dateIcon, 'mat-icon');
  this.renderer.addClass(dateIcon, 'material-icons');
```

**Full code if curious. -->**

```
for (let j = this.requestVehicle.startDateTime.getDate(); j < this.requestVehicle.endDateTime.getDate(); j++) {
  const newTime = new Date(time.getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000);
  time = newTime;

  const date = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  const dateIcon = this.renderer.createElement('mat-icon');
  this.renderer.appendChild(dateIcon, this.renderer.createText('today'));
  this.renderer.addClass(dateIcon, 'mat-icon');
  this.renderer.addClass(dateIcon, 'material-icons');
  this.renderer.appendChild(date, dateIcon);
  this.renderer.appendChild(date, this.renderer.createText(newTime.getDate() + '/' + newTime.getMonth() + '/' + newTime.getFullYear()));
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.d7.nativeElement, date);

  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    const b = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const icon = this.renderer.createElement('mat-icon');
    if (i < 7 || i > 18) {
      this.renderer.appendChild(icon, this.renderer.createText('brightness_3'));
    } else {
      this.renderer.appendChild(icon, this.renderer.createText('wb_sunny'));
    }
    let text;
    if (i >= 10) {
      text = ' ' + i;
    } else {
      text = '0' + i;
    }
    this.renderer.appendChild(b, icon);
    this.renderer.addClass(icon, 'mat-icon');
    this.renderer.addClass(icon, 'material-icons');
    this.renderer.appendChild(b, this.renderer.createText(text + ':00'));
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.d3.nativeElement, b);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the similar issue. Your method would work, but it's not good enough. If the mat-icon is static HTML tag, it won't ask for classes, why would it needs them for dynamic contents? Further, what could you do if you want to bind an action for it? Apparently, "(click = someFunction($event))" wouldn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by static HTML tag on mat-icon. but for actions you can probably use renderer.listen . let me know if you find better solution.